# Color don't apply on a p5.js example with noise function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to implement a p5.js example of the Nature of Code book.

The aim is to fill a canvas with pixels which brightness is randomly chosen by the Perlin Noise function. I was inspired by the Processing's Java equivalent one but what I obtain is not why I expected, it is an almost black canvas.

This is my code :

```
var increment = 0.02

function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 100)
  noLoop()
}

function draw() {
  background(0)

  loadPixels();

  var xoff = 0

  for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    xoff += increment
    var yoff = 0

    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      yoff += increment
      var bright = floor(noise(xoff, yoff) * 255)

      console.log('bright', bright, '(', x, ', ', y, ')')

      pixels[x+y*width] = color(bright);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

My console.log displays a bright value which seems coherent. 
Do you see any problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pixels array is flat with each 4 elements creating a pixel.

The first pixel is actually:

```
pixels[0] // red value of pixel,   between 0-255
pixels[1] // green value of pixel, between 0-255
pixels[2] // blue value of pixel,  between 0-255
pixels[3] // alpha value of pixel, between 0-255
```

However, when looking through the p5.js documentation I noticed there is a [helper method `set`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/set) which abstracts the setting of a pixel's color.  To use the `set` method all we need is a pixel's coordinates as well as a [`color` instance](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/color).  Changing the color mode also allows us to easily create a color object with a given brightness.

*Note: I've included a CDN link to p5.js so you can run the example.*

```js
const increment = 0.02;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  
  colorMode(HSB, 255);
  
  let xOff = 0;
  
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    let yOff = 0;
    
    xOff += increment;
    
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      yOff += increment
      
      const n = noise(xOff, yOff);    //  noise
      const h = 255;                  //  hue
      const s = 126;                  //  saturation
      const b = map(n, 0, 1, 0, 255); //  brightness
      const c = color(h, s, b);       //  color instance
      
      set(x, y, c);                   //  set pixel
    }
  }
  
  updatePixels();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.8/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works like a charm with set, thanks!

Why did you use the HSB mode instead the RGBA?

Comment: I used HSB because it allows us to create a colour with a specified brightness, the alpha property of RGBA isn't actually the same as brightness, it means how transparent/opaque the colour is.